# QGIS layer properties window oversized

Tags: qgis, windows, point-cloud

With the latest version of QGIS (3.28.2) with Windows 64 bits, with the new point cloud layer: the layer properties window is oversized in the height. This hides the bottom buttons (OK, Cancel...), even when the Windows task bar is hidden. There is no mean of resizing this window, or scrolling...

My laptop size is 1920 x 1080, which is the standard for this kind of laptop.

Is this a common issue, and is there a fix to come? Or maybe a tip for the display on my screen?

[image]

Comment: Please open a bug report (like https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32021 )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot scroll, because the buttons area is generally not in scrollable area.

[image]

Since I use multiple screens which have different resolution, I frequently encounter this problem. Reduce the size by clicking it from top margin.

[image]