# View more than three pictures in the image viewer of QGIS

Tags: qgis, image, viewer

I'm adding photos inside point fields in a GeoPackage table in QGIS. The default image viewer cannot show more than three photos and the window is not scrollable.

[image: Default image viewer in QGIS. The windows is not scrollable. There are more photos]

[image: There are more than 3 photos. The window is non-scrollable]

Is there any settings so that I can view more photos in the default viewer?
Are there any plugins for that ?

Comment: Try to resize the window as in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448191/29431).

Answer (score 8):

It appears you can do this by explicitly setting a width and a height for the image in the section *Integrated Document Viewer* (to the bottom-right of your last screenshot). Instead of the images resizing to fit the window, a scroll bar will be added.

[image]

Note: you can also leave the width blank for it to be automatically calculated from the height you set.

Answer (score 2):

I have used a different technique to solve the problem (though the full image doesn't appear and I have to scroll to see more). I added a new Tab for each of the photo. It solved part of my problem, but the photo is still not displayed in full and I still have to scroll to see some part of the photo. It appears to be the problem with how the photo is displayed on screens with different resolution. I have a monitor connected to my laptop. This is how the photo is displayed in the laptop monitor and the secondary monitor:

1. Laptop screen : [image: Resolution 1920 x 1080 14"]
2. Secondary monitor : [image: Same resolution 1920 x 1080 but bigger screen 21"]

It seems like image viewer needs some work